unitary that transform $\sigma^x \pm \alpha \sigma^z$ into $\sigma^x$ and $\sigma^z$
Consider $\sigma^x \pm \sigma^z$, where $\sigma^x$ and $\sigma^z$ are Pauli $X$ and $Z$ matrices. Let unitary $U$ be a $\pi/4$ rotation matrix around $Y$-axis. Then,
\begin{equation}
U(\sigma^x + \sigma^z)U^\dagger \propto \sigma^x, \quad U(\sigma^x - \sigma^z)U^\dagger \propto \sigma^z,
\end{equation} where $\propto$ refers to the equality sign up to a constant factor.
I want to generalize this problem. Specifically, what would be a unitary $U$ that satisfies:
\begin{equation}
U(\sigma^x + \alpha \sigma^z)U^\dagger \propto \sigma^x, \quad U(\sigma^x - \alpha \sigma^z)U^\dagger \propto \sigma^z,
\end{equation} where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is a fixed non-zero constant? Does this unitary even exist in the first place?

$U$ is simply a change in basis for these operators. The  eigenvectors of $X+\alpha Z$ gets mapped to the eigenvalues of $X$, which should give most of the structure $U$ immediately.

Short answer: Such a unitary $U$ exists if and only if $\alpha=1$ or $\alpha=-1$
Long answer:
Because $\sigma_x-\alpha\sigma_z$ are traceless matrices with determinant $-\alpha^2-1$ their eigenvalues are $-\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}$. Thus any unitary $U$ which diagonalizes $\sigma_x-\alpha\sigma_z$ has to satisfy${}^1$
$$
U(\sigma_x-\alpha\sigma_z)U^\dagger=\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}\sigma_z\,.\tag1
$$
This is our starting point: let $U$ be a general element of $\mathsf{SU}(2)$, i.e.
$$
U=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\phi)e^{i\xi}&\sin(\phi)e^{i\omega}\\
-\sin(\phi)e^{-i\omega}&\cos(\phi)e^{-i\xi}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $\phi,\xi,\omega\in\mathbb R$. We have to tune the parameters such that, equivalently to (1),
$$
\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}U^\dagger\sigma_z U=\sigma_x-\alpha\sigma_z=\begin{pmatrix}-\alpha&1\\1&\alpha\end{pmatrix}.\tag2
$$
A straightforward computation shows that
$$
\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}U^\dagger\sigma_z U=\begin{pmatrix}
 \sqrt{\alpha^2+1} \cos (2 \phi ) & \sqrt{\alpha^2+1} e^{i (\omega -\xi )} \sin (2 \phi ) \\
 \sqrt{\alpha^2+1} e^{-i (\omega -\xi )} \sin (2 \phi ) & -\sqrt{\alpha^2+1} \cos (2 \phi )
\end{pmatrix}
$$
meaning that $\sqrt{\alpha^2+1} \cos (2 \phi )$ has to equal $-\alpha$. Thus we find
$
\cos(2\phi)=\frac{-\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}}
$, that is, $$\phi=\frac12\arccos\Big(\frac{-\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}}\Big)\in[0,\pi]$$ (which is well defined because $\frac{-\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}}\in(-1,1)$). With this choice of $\phi$
$$
\sqrt{\alpha^2+1} \sin (2 \phi )=\sqrt{\alpha^2+1} \sqrt{1-(\cos (2 \phi ))^2}=\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}\sqrt{1-\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2+1}}=1
$$
so
$$
\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}U^\dagger\sigma_z U=\begin{pmatrix}
 -\alpha & e^{i (\omega -\xi )} \\
 e^{-i (\omega -\xi )} &\alpha
\end{pmatrix};
$$
comparing with (2) shows $e^{i \omega}=e^{i\xi }$.
But with these choices of $\phi,\omega$ one readily verifies that
$$
U(\sigma_x+\alpha\sigma_z)U^\dagger=
\frac1{\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1-\alpha^2 & -2 \alpha e^{2 i \omega} \\
 -2 \alpha e^{-2 i \omega}&\alpha^2-1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
which is proportional to $\sigma_x$ (in particular: has zero diagonal) if and only if $\alpha^2=1$.


1: Actually, $U(\sigma_x-\alpha\sigma_z)U^\dagger=-\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}\sigma_z$ would also be allowed but that case is handled analogously.


Let $A$ and $B$ be your two initial matrices. You have
$$
\text{Tr}(AB)=2(1-\alpha^2).
$$
After the unitary, you have
$$
\text{Tr}(UAU^\dagger UBU^\dagger)=\text{Tr}(AB)=2(1-\alpha^2).
$$
Your aim is to have this value be 0. That can only happen if $\alpha=\pm1$.

A nice solution, way more elegant than my brute-force approach!
